# MVC Helper @Html.LabelFor not showing up?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, html.labelfor

Am I missing a reference or something?

I have a reference to System.Web.Mvc 4.0x

But whenever I try this

```
 @Html.LabelFor(x=>Model.yadda, new {id="_lblYadda"});
```

I get nothing I can't even get it to compile. I only have a reference to

```
 @Html.Label("Yadda", "Yadda yadda");
```

I spent like 5 minutes looking, I know it's simple so.. help please!

WebConfig namespaces are:

```
 <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
```

Comment: Do you include the namespace `System.Web.Mvc.Html` in your web.config?

Comment: Please include more information about the compilation error

Comment: Did you upgrade/convert a project? I have never had to mess with this besides adding my own namespaces. Maybe try restarting VS?

Comment: Error is the common: Reference to LabelFor not found... I noticed that if I write this @System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor() I can get to the extension definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue:

I noticed that the project that works references System.Web.Mvc.Html and the one that I'm using for @Html.Label() references System.Web.WebPages.dll

I removed the reference to System.Web.WebPages.dll and now it works with all the extensions.

System.Web.WebPages.dll is crap... The End... THanks